# Make auctex ask me only for position and width when inserting a minipage environment

Tags: latex, auctex

If I insert a minipage environment using auctex `LaTeX-environment` it asks me for "Position", "Height", "Inner Position" and "Width". However I only want to be asked for "Position" and "Width". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AUCTeX in general queries for the next optional argument if the current one is filled with some text and is not a empty string (which is simply  hitting <kbd>RET</kbd> by the user).  For me, when I hit <kbd>C-c C-e minipage RET</kbd>, AUCTeX queries for the `(Optional) Position` and if I leave this empty and hit <kbd>RET</kbd>, it takes me directly to the mandatory `Width` with `1.0\linewidth` as default.  Maybe you're using a completion infrastructure like `vertico` which chooses and inserts the first optional argument and then you get queries for more.